# Limit Meteor.js built-in Google authentication to a domain

Tags: meteor, google-oauth

I'd like to use the `Meteor.loginWithGoogle()` tool to authenticate users, but is there any way to limit it to a specific (Google Apps) domain?

I could check after the user is authenticated using the returned email, but is there a way to do this at the login stage with some parameter for Google login?

Comment: What do you mean by "limit it to a specific domain"? Do you mean you only want gmail users with a .com or .co.uk address? Or do you mean your application runs on multiple domains and you only want google auth to work on one of those? Something else?

Comment: I meant a Google Apps domain, so you should only be allowed to login with a @<domain>.com account, and not with any other Google account.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I dont think its possible right now. 
There is a pull resquest to partly add that functionality: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/1332
The issue with that pull request seems to be that it only fixes the client side of thinges (ie. it only shows accounts from the selected domain when the user logs in).
But it does not add any server side checks.

Im using the following workaround:
In a .js file in the sever folder I have the following code:

```
Accounts.validateNewUser(function (user) {
    if(user.services.google.email.match(/example\.org$/)) {
        return true;
    }
    throw new Meteor.Error(403, "You must sign in using a example.org account");
});
```

This prevents accounts from being made for domains different from example.org.

Comment: It's build in: `Accounts.config({restrictCreationByEmailDomain: 'mydomain.com'})`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only allow certain users from your domain, you could also add a whitelist collection that defines user ids from your Google Apps account. This way you can restrict access to only certain users, get single sign-on functionality, and can pre-set user roles and properties for your app before users even create their accounts.

Use the `Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){})` callback for that since it allows you to define additional user properties.